# join results from two sql tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to get results from two tables grouped by same rules joined together in one select.

I have table 1

```
create table person AS 
id INTEGER,
gender INTEGER,
state VARCHAR2
name VARCHAR2
surname VARCHAR2
```

table 2

```
create table sampletest as
person_id FOREIGN KEY To person.id
result INTEGER
```

table 3

```
create table examtest as 
person_id FOREIGN KEY to person.id
examresult INTEGER
```

I would like to get this output

group by state   |   group by gender | count(examresult>0) | count(result>0 and result<4)

I tried something like this

```
select state,gender,count(e.examresult),count(s.result) where 
p.id=s.person_id and p.id=e.person_id and 
s.result>0 and s.result<4 and 
e.examresult>0 group by state,gender
```

but i get results that are dependent on each other. How do i get independent results into one select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build sub-selects

```
select
  p.state,
  p.gender,
  sum( 
    ( select count(1) from examtest e 
      where e.personid = p.personid 
      and e.examresult > 0 ) ) as examcount,
  sum( 
    ( select count(1) from sampletest s 
      where s.personid = p.personid
      and s.result > 0 and s.result < 4) ) as samplecount
from
  person p
group by
  p.state,
  p.gender
```

Comment: could you help out a bit more, i need count 0 for states,genders that dont have e.examresult grouped by 0,1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Correlated subqueries are a poor solution from a performance perspective. THis should never be your first choice.

Comment: I write queries like this, sometimes hundreds of lines long, and they usually outperform other solutions. This probably will depend on the database you use. When using Oracle, a rule of thumb is that the worse your query looks, the better it usually performs. But the left join in the other answer will probably work fine and maybe even better.

Answer (score 3):

```
  SELECT state,gender,
         SUM(CASE WHEN e.examresult > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EXAM_GT_ZERO,
         SUM(CASE WHEN s.result BETWEEN 0 AND 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SMPL_0_to_4
    FROM person p
         LEFT JOIN sampletest s
         ON p.id = s.person_id 
         LEFT JOIN examtest e
         ON p.id = e.person_id
GROUP BY state,gender
```